# How to dynamically print list values?

Tags: python

This Code Works Fine.....But it's like static.
I don't know what to do to make it work in dynamic way?
I want:-
When user inputs 3 number of cities it should give

> a="You would like to visit "+li[0]+" as city 1 and " +li[1]+ " as city
>   2 and "+li[2]+" as city 3 on your trip"

Similaraly when input is 5 cities it should go to 5 times

```
li = []
global a

number_of_cities = int(raw_input("Enter Number of Cities -->"))
for city in range(number_of_cities):
   li.append(raw_input("Enter City Name -->"))
print li
a="You would like to visit "+li[0]+" as city 1 and " +li[1]+ " as city 2 and "+li[2]+" as city 3 on your trip"      
print a
a = a.split(" ")
print "\nSplitted First Sentence looks like"
print a
print "\nJoined First Sentence and added 1"
index = 0
for word in a:
   if word.isdigit():
      a[index] = str(int(word)+1)
   index += 1
print " ".join(a)
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
a = 'You would like to visit ' + ' and '.join('{0} as city {1}'.format(city, index) for index, city in enumerate(li, 1)) + ' on your trip'
```

Comment: But what does '{0} as city {1}' in your code mean??

Comment: If the arguments in `format` are in the same order as the references `{}` in the string, the numbers are optional.

Comment: @StavanShah it is string formatting you can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: @nostradamus numbers are optional, but if you explicitly specify them, you format function will work slightly faster

Answer (score 0):

You can build the string with a combination of [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
a = "You would like to visit {} on your trip".format(
    " and ".join("{} as city {}".format(city, i)
                 for i, city in enumerate(li, 1)))
```

`str.join()` is given a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) as the iterable argument. The curly braces (`{}`) in the strings are [replacement fields](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) (placeholders), which will be replaced by positional arguments when formatting. For example

```
'{} {}'.format('a', 'b')
```

will produce the string `"a b"`, as will

```
# explicit positional argument specifiers
'{0} {1}'.format('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

create another for loop and save your cities to an array. afterwords, concat the array using "join" and put put everything inside the string:

```
cities = []
for i in range(0,len(li), 1):
    cities.append("%s as city %i" % (li[i], i))

cities_str = " and ".join(cities)
a = "You would like to visit %s on your trip" % (cities_str) # edited out the + sign
```

Comment: sorry, it should be like this:
a = "You would like to visit %s on your trip" % (cities_str)